# Make `rsync --link-dest` find files recursively

Tags: rsync, symlink, recursive

I'm using Rsync as a backup tool. When I create a new backup, I would like it to look in all the existing backup folders for each file and if it already exists, create a hard link.

From the [Rsync man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync),

> Beginning in version 2.6.4, multiple --link-dest directories may be
>       provided, which will cause rsync to search the list in the order specified for an exact match.

I could create a list with all my backup folders and pass the list to --link-dest, however I suspect that there must be a better solution.

Can I use a wildcard in the DIR argument of --link-dest? (I tried * but it didn't work).

Can I make `--link-dest` search for files recursively? I tried setting DIR to my top backup folder and using `--recursive`, but it didn't find the files and it created a new file instead of a hard link.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you need `--link-dest=$item` for each item of your list of backup directories.

If you want those `--link-dest=` arguments generated from a  glob, you can do:

```
 printf ' --link-dest=%q ' *
```

Comment: Thanks, that command helps, but I cannot make it work when my link-dest folder is in a remote location.

Comment: @try can you do something like `ssh remote sh -c ":; cd target_directory; printf ' --link-dest=%q ' *"` to generate the the arguments?

Comment: It's worth noting that multiple `--link-dest` stops on the first found file. Imagine you backup a file, then modify the file, then backup again, then undo the modification and backup a third time so that the first an third backups are the same. You wll get three files, not two: the first and third won't be hard-linked even though they are the same.